# VBA Code for Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

When I reference a specific cell in `vlookup` VBA code like below I can get the code to return the correct answer.

```
Application.VLookup(Sheets("Setup").Cells(2, 1),
Sheets("Download").Range("A:G"), 7, 0)
```

However, if I replace the code with a variable (`VLDate`) then I get an error

```
Application.VLookup(VLDate, Sheets("Download").Range("A:G"), 7, 0)
```

I've tried to make Dim `VLDate` As String but this didn't work too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by `didn't work`? Do you get an error message? Does it not find anything? What are you returning the result of the `VLookup` to? Provide more code and more context in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `Sheets("Setup").Cells(2,1)` is not a string.

`Cells` returns a Range.

```
Dim VLDate As Range
Set VLDate = Sheet("Setup").Cells(2,1)
```

If your first example worked, using the above code to set the value of VLDate should make your second example work too.

**Edit**
Might have misunderstood your question a little so while the above is true it might not help!

Could you provide an example value for VLDate, and also the cell formatting type and an example value from the range that its looked up in?

Comment: According to the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is. The `vlookup`'s first input has to be of the same data type of what you're looking for. For example if in the cells you are searching you have only numbers, then try dimensioning VLDate as a number, if you try to dim it as string it won't find a match and will give you the type mismatch error.

You can dim VLDate as `variant`, which is easier, but do not use quotes if you're looking for a number.

try adding, for debugging purposes, the line

```
MsgBox(CStr(Application.VLookup(Sheets("Setup").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Download").Range("A:G"), 7, 0))
```

and if you het a msgbox with `Error 2042` it menas it couldn't find a match, therefore you should be using the wrong data type.

The only situation that you use string is if the destination cells contain something like ="21" in their formulas, because then it is a string.

hope it helps